# Drupal 7 Content type dropdown language selection

Tags: drupal

I am newer in drupal , I am trying to create a content type with multi lingual support . I have the modules and which translate all the things in my site . But when I am trying to translate the content type from admin , there is no dropdown menu for language selection .

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to have enabled some 'multi lingual modules' 
like locale,content translation , languages and set up their options .
For example you need to configure the languages you'll be using here :

```
admin/config/regional/language
```

and set up the extra language settings e.g path here admin/config/regional/language/configure
then you need to go to admin/structure/types/manage/[my-content-type] or if you want the page content type to be translated  (default drupal's content type) go here admin/structure/types/manage/page ( page is your current content type )
and click at the 'Publishing Options' Tab and select Multilingual support -> Enabled, with translation.

After this you'll see next to every page-node display the new 'translation tab'
Then you need to download this life savior module :)

http://drupal.org/project/i18n